# Suppress namespace when printing ::keyword

Tags: printing, clojure, keyword, suppress

When I write

```
 (println '(:keyword1 :keyword2))
```

I get the following output:

> (:keyword1 :keyword2)

and it's ok.

But when I write

```
(println '(::keyword1 ::keyword2))
```

I get this

> (:namespace/keyword1 :namespace/keyword2)

And I want to get

> (::keyword1 ::keyword2)

Is it possible? I just make symbolic computations with lots of keywords and I need to print them.

I tried this: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/*print-suppress-namespaces* but it did not help.

Thank you for any advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printing machinery in Clojure is based on multimethods. It is possible to take advantage of that in order to change how namespaced keywords are printed. Altering the way keywords are printed may not be wise in general though.

The multimethod used to produce the output for human consumption is called [print-method](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3563). It takes two arguments - the object to print and the output Writer. The dispatch is performed on the type of the object being printed, roughly speaking. Thus it is possible to re-define the `print-method` for `clojure.lang.Keyword` type. The [default implementation](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core_print.clj#L116) of that method can be used as for reference.

It is also necessary to find out if a keyword has a namespace component - this is how we can determine if we should print one colon or two. The `getNamespace` method in the [Keyword](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Keyword.java) class will do the job. At this point we are way too deep into Clojure implementation details. Proceed at your own risk.

```
(import 'clojure.lang.Keyword)
;=> clojure.lang.Keyword
(import 'java.io.Writer)
;=> java.io.Writer
(defmethod print-method Keyword [^Keyword k, ^Writer w]
  (if (.getNamespace k)
    (.write w (str "::" (name k)))
    (.write w (str k))))
;=> #object[clojure.lang.MultiFn 0x24243e9f "clojure.lang.MultiFn@24243e9f"]
(println ::foo)
;=> ::foo
;=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Good question, I find this behavior annoying too. If you want a relatively local fix, here's a macro that will temporarily change the printing behavior of keywords and suppress the namespace-qualified map notation, which is annoying in `pprint`. Note that these changes will be visible from all threads during the body of the macro, also that this is going to print Keywords much slower than the normal method. Most of the time that's not a problem, however.

If a qualified keyword's namespace is aliased in the current namespace, it will print the keyword with that alias.

```
(defn short-keyword-print [^clojure.lang.Keyword kw, ^Writer w]
  (if-let [ns-str (.getNamespace kw)]
    (if-let [ns (find-ns (symbol ns-str))]
      (if (= ns *ns*)
        (.write w (str "::" (name kw)))
        (if-let [ns-alias (some #(when (= ns (val %)) (key %)) (ns-aliases *ns*))]
          (.write w (str "::" ns-alias "/" (name kw)))
          (.write w (str "::?/" (name kw)))))
      (.write w (str "::?/" (name kw))))
    (.write w (str ":" (name kw)))))

(defmacro with-short-keys [& body]
  `(binding [*print-namespace-maps* false]
     (let [old-kw-method# (get (methods print-method) clojure.lang.Keyword)]
       (. ~(with-meta `print-method {:tag 'clojure.lang.MultiFn})
         addMethod clojure.lang.Keyword short-keyword-print)
       (try
         ~@body
         (finally
           (. ~(with-meta `print-method {:tag 'clojure.lang.MultiFn})
             addMethod clojure.lang.Keyword old-kw-method#))))))
```

Then:

```
(require '[clojure.set :as set])

(with-short-keys
  (dorun
    (map println
      [:x                      ; unqualified
       ::x                     ; qualified with this namespace
       ::set/x                 ; qualified with aliased namespace
       :clojure.set/x          ; qualified with aliased namespace, but not using the alias
       :clojure.data/x         ; qualified with real but un-aliased namespace
       :some-other-namespace/x ; qualified with unreal un-aliased namespace
       ])))
```

This prints:

```
:x        ; unqualified
::x       ; qualified with this namespace
::set/x   ; qualified with aliased namespace
::set/x   ; qualified with aliased namespace, but not using the alias
::?/x     ; qualified with real but un-aliased namespace
::?/x     ; qualified with unreal un-aliased namespace
```

Answer (score -1):

The purpose of the double-colon notation is to insert the current namespace into the keyword.  The purpose of the single-colon notation is to create a keyword without a namespace. Thus, it makes little sense to ask,

> "How can I add a namspace and then pretend that it isn't there?"

The best answer is to decide whether or not you want to add a namespace to your keyword, then choose the appropriate technique.